# How to stop VSCode from adding 'package' to java files

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, redhat, vscode-extensions

#### Background

I installed all the VSCode 'Extension Pack for Java' when I started working with Java, this included:

- Debugger for Java
- Project Manager for Java
- Maven for Java
- IntelliCode
- Test Runner for Java
- Language Support for Java(TM) by RedHat

#### Problem

The Extension "Language Support for Java(TM) by Red Hat" will attempt to add a `package` to each file you are working in automatically.  However for the class I am in the grading tool asks you remove 'package' from the files before submitting.  I can't seem to find a way to disable this and I am not as familiar with editing VSCode settings.

#### What I have tried

I tried just disabling the extensions but now I don't have access to the required `.jars` since disabling this extension also disables the ability to add .`jars`  to your class path via IDE.

Comment: Do you mean the `package` statement? Or the import statement. Maybe add some snippet/screenshot to help people understand your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may not be the best solution but for some reason if I `disable` then `enable` "Language Support for Java(TM) by Red Hat" it stops prompting to add package...

Not sure if this is the recommended solution so curious if anyone else knows a better way.