# Reconfigure VSCode/RedHat Automatic Package Import in Java Files

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, templates, package, redhat

Whenever a Java file is created/saved in VSCode (using VSCode Project Manager for Java & RedHat Language Support extensions), the package (directory structure) is automatically added to the top of the file, along with the automatic creation of the class body.

```
package Example/Package/Name;

public class ExampleClass {
    
}
```

Since my directory structure is not configured for Java packages exclusively, more often than not, I end up having to remove the package that is automatically imported.

I don't want to disable language support altogether, so I've been looking for a way to either reconfigure the package import statement, or for a way to create a default "new file template" for `.java` files.

However, I haven't found a way do that, other than using "snippets", which seems like a work-around, not a solution.

I've also tried editing my `settings.json`, but it seems the extent of what I can do there is limited to type comments and file headers (which don't address the package import or file body).

```
"java.templates.typeComment":
"java.templates.fileHeader":
```

I have not been able to find any information on this topic, apart from this SO post here that was not adequately resolved: [Stop VSCode from Adding Package to Java Files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74671558/how-to-stop-vscode-from-adding-package-to-java-files).

Or this issue request on GitHub, which wanted to remove both the package and class body auto import: [RedHat Developer Issues](https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/issues/2652).

I've scoured VSCode & RedHat docs but the VSCode documentation simply mentions that code completion is provided by Language Support from RedHat, but does not mention a way to configure it specifically: [VSCode Docs Java](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-editing).

Comment: Post your point of view on the original link or create a new one to report your detailed needs.

Comment: You already know that VSCode's existing features cannot achieve your needs. What do you expect from here? Please report your feature request in Github.

Comment: what _exactly_ do you mean by "_reconfigure the package import statement_" ?

Comment: @JialeDu That was going to be my next step. However, because there were so few sources that directly addressed this issue, I didn't want to definitively conclude that this should be a feature request without first seeking additional input.

Comment: @starball When you save a `.java` file in VSCode, Intellisense will automatically configure the class body (using the file name) and the package import (based on the project's directory structure). I find the class body import useful, along with other Intellisense features, so I do not want to disable it completely. However, my directory structure is not set up such that I want it to be automatically included as a package import. It seems simple enough that I thought you might be able to configure where/what the imported package is using `settings.json`, or something similar, but it seems not.

Comment: If you have new actions, don’t forget to share them here.